# How should I detect if a python interpretor is conda enabled?

Tags: anaconda, miniconda

By conda enabled I mean that's one of the two blends of Python that are published but Continuum Analytics (Anaconda and Miniconda).

My original implementation was `if 'conda' in sys.version` but it seems that will not work as expected.

It seems that miniconda reports something like `Python 3.5.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.`

#### Why I need to detect this?

That's because we want to change the build-script behaviour based on on this and use conda installer instead of pip for some tasks.

Comment: This question is now a duplicate of [*How to detect from within Python whether packages are managed with conda*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608532/how-to-detect-from-within-python-whether-packages-are-managed-with-conda), whose comprehensive question *and* numerous high-quality answers supersede those provided here. Praise be to [the definitive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610844/2809027)!

Answer (score 0):

While I do not find the code beautiful that's my current implementation:

```
import sys
if 'conda' in sys.version or 'Continuum' in sys.version: print("conda!")
```